# Need some suggestions with Relationship fields and CPT/ACF

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, user-roles, forms, user-meta

I am tasked with creating a Student/Teacher Portal where among other things, I need a way to build a way for Admins to assign Teacher with Students based upon Subject and Age group (Age for students). The Teacher and Student also receives an Email with an update message when the Teacher relationship is updated by an admin.

**My thought process:**

I am planning to Create two user roles for teacher and student, The Teacher user role will contain additional data such as Subjects and Age group with Custom Fields.

Then create a 'Applications' Post type(CPT) and use a frontend form with permission for Students to submit where they will have the same Custom fields of Subjects and Age. It'll also contain two Relationships to assign the Student and Teacher User Role.

If I follow this thought process, I need a way autofill the Student relationship, either by the Frontend form or have a filter in the relationship field to only show the post author (or autofill the post author?)

I will also need a way to Filter the Teacher Relationship based upon the Subject and Age group on their Custom field.

Finally, I will need to send Emails to both users. (I was planning to do this with Suretriggers, But I will need a way to pull the data of user email of both relationships from the 'Application' post)

I am also wondering if there's a better way to implement this altogether than my current thought process.